# How to use setInterval() inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please find my code below.

```js
for (i= 0; i < region.length; i++) {
                    point = region[i];
                    animation = setInterval(function () {
                     ..........
                    }, 12);
                }
```

I want to execute the codes in setInterval before i value changes from 0 to 1. But currently after all the execution of for loop only, codes in the setInterval method is getting executed. is there any way to achieve my requirement.

Comment: @Rajesh thanks for your comment. But I want to execute the codes inside the setInterval method, before the further increment of i value in the for loop.

Comment: apologies for my misunderstanding.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583280/javascript-execute-async-function-one-by-one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use closure inside for loop:

```js
(function(i) {
  setInterval(function() {
    console.log("inside setinterval" + i)
  }, 10);
})(i)
```

hope this solves your problem

Comment: It helps me a lot. But I want to maintain the same 'i' value until calling clearInterval()  method. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Async loop you need:

```
var len = region.length;
var i = 0;
var animate = function(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        point = region[i];
        //do something..........
        if (i++ < len) animate();
    }, 12);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use recursion for such requirements. Also, you should use `setTimeout` as `setInterval` will run for eternity(*till page exists*) until you clear it.

```js
var i = 0;
var MAX_COUNT = 10;
function doSomething(str){
  console.log(str);
  processData();
}

function initSetTimeout(callback){
  setTimeout(callback, 1000)
}

function processData(){
  if(++i<MAX_COUNT)
    initSetTimeout(doSomething.bind(null, i))
}
processData()
```