# Execute async function twice after previous one is completed

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to execute an `async` function twice one after another. But the problem is that they are executing together. But, what I want is that the 2nd execution must be start after the execution of first is completed.

> PS, there are many questions on SO, with same title, like this one [JavaScript: execute async function one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13583280/7575841). But none of them solve my problem.

Please, check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iNullPointer/r5yft4uq/11/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function typeWriter(element, msg, speed, index = 0) {
    if (index < msg.length) {
      $(element).html($(element).html() + msg.charAt(index++));
      setTimeout(function() {
        typeWriter(element, msg, speed, index);
      }, speed);
    }
  }

  $('.intro').fadeIn(function() {
    const greet = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      typeWriter('#sayHello', "Hello !!", 200);
      resolve();
    });
    greet.then(function() {
      typeWriter('#myName', "I'm learning programming", 200);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.intro {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  font-family: 'Amaranth', sans-serif;
}

.cursor {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: inherit !important;
}

.cursor>span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 26px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from,
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro">
  <h1 class="title"><span id="sayHello"></span><span class="cursor"><span></span></span>
  </h1>
  <h1 class="title"><span id="myName"></span><span class="cursor"><span></span></span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Here, I'm trying to `print` two lines of text inside two different `<h1>` tags. For that, I'm calling `function typeWriter(...)` twice, once for each `<h1>`. I'm trying to `print` two lines, one after completion of previous one, i.e., print `Hello !!` in first call and after it finishes then print `I'm Learning Programming` in second line, but it is not happening. The problem is they are executing together.

On further searching for the solution, I found this question [JavaScript: execute async function one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13583280/7575841), and follow answer given by [@DavidHedlund](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13583592/7575841), but It doesn't work for me. Sorry, if I'm making any mistake. 
Please take a look of the fiddle that I tried from [@DavidHedlund](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13583592/7575841) answer. In this case, only `Hello !!` is printed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function typeWriter(element, msg, speed, index = 0) {
    if (index < msg.length) {
      $(element).html($(element).html() + msg.charAt(index++));
      setTimeout(function() {
        typeWriter(element, msg, speed, index);
      }, speed);
    }
  }

  $('.intro').fadeIn(function() {

    function executeTasks() {
      var tasks = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arguments);
      var task = tasks.shift();
      task(function() {
        if (tasks.length > 0)
          executeTasks.apply(this, tasks);
      });
    }

    function createTask(param) {
      let element = param[0];
      let msg = param[1];
      let speed = param[2];
      return function(callback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          if (typeof callback == 'function') typeWriter(element, msg, speed);
        }, 1);
      }
    }
    var t1 = createTask(['#sayHello', "Hello !!", 200]);
    var t2 = createTask(['#myName', "I'm Anshuman Gupta", 200]);
    executeTasks(t1, t2);
  });
});
```

```css
.intro {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  font-family: 'Amaranth', sans-serif;
}

.cursor {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: inherit !important;
}

.cursor>span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 26px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from,
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro">
  <h1 class="title"><span id="sayHello"></span><span class="cursor"><span></span></span>
  </h1>
  <h1 class="title"><span id="myName"></span><span class="cursor"><span></span></span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

**Thank you!!**

Comment: In the first code-sample you have given, the "I am learning programming" starts after `typeWriter('#sayHello', "Hello !!", 200);` returns. So, if `typeWriter('#sayHello', "Hello !!", 200);` returns immediately (and does not wait for the text animation to complete) the next part will get executed.

Comment: @ZeekHuge, please note that  function `typeWriter` is a `recursive function`, which call itself untill the `length` of the message, `Hello !!` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, whats happening here is, the `typeWriter()` method is using a `setTimeout()`, which works on a threaded model (that is `setTimeout()` will not block the thread, instead will return immediately). That is why, the `typeWriter()` method returns immediately, and therefore the corresponding promise resolves.

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function typeWriter(element, msg, speed) {
        return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
            var recursive = function (element, msg, speed, index) {
                if (index < msg.length) {
                    $(element).html($(element).html() + msg.charAt(index++));
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        recursive(element, msg, speed, index);
                    }, speed)
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            }
            recursive(element, msg, speed, 0)
        })
        }

    $('.intro').fadeIn(function() {
        typeWriter('#sayHello', "Hello !!", 200).then(function() {
            return typeWriter('#myName', "I'm learning programming", 200);
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ZeekHuge, you save my day.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use `await` if that seems simpler for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function typeWriter(element, msg, speed, index = 0) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (index < msg.length) {
        $(element).html($(element).html() + msg.charAt(index++));
        setTimeout(function() {
          typeWriter(element, msg, speed, index).then(resolve).catch(reject);
        }, speed);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  }
  
  async function typeStuff() {
    console.log("Hi");
    await typeWriter('#sayHello', "Hello !!", 200);
    await typeWriter('#myName', "I'm learning programming", 200);
  }

  $('.intro').fadeIn(function() {
    typeStuff();
  });
});
```

```css
.intro {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  font-family: 'Amaranth', sans-serif;
}

.cursor {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: inherit !important;
}

.cursor>span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 26px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  animation: blink 1s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from,
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro">
  <h1 class="title"><span id="sayHello"></span><span class="cursor"><span></span></span>
  </h1>
  <h1 class="title"><span id="myName"></span><span class="cursor"><span></span></span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Explanation: in your code, you called `resolve` immediately after calling `typeWriter`. The issue is that `typeWriter` does not "block," meaning it sets a timeout to execute code in the future and immediately returns. You can avoid this my making `typeWriter` a promise. Then, you can either use `await` (which is cleaner but less supported by browsers) or `typeWriter(...).then(function() { /* Do more stuff */ })` (they are essentially equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you do not wait for the recursion function to finish and then call resolve.

```
 const greet = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  typeWriter('#sayHello', "Hello !!", 200);
  resolve();
});
greet.then(function() {
  typeWriter('#myName', "I'm learning programming", 200);
});
```

Try this:

```
const timeout = (speed) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
    }, speed);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
async function typeWriter(element, msg, speed, index = 0) {
  if (index < msg.length) {
    $(element).html($(element).html() + msg.charAt(index++));
    await timeout(speed);
    await typeWriter(element, msg, speed, index);
  }
}

$('.intro').fadeIn(function() {
    const greet = new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
      await typeWriter('#sayHello', "Hello !!", 200);
      resolve();
    });
    greet.then(function() {
      typeWriter('#myName', "I'm learning programming", 200);
    });
  });
});
```